# After executing Navigator.pop(context) inside onPressed, the remaining lines still gets executed. How?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (ctx) => const Filter(),
                  ),
                );
              },
```

This is my code.. My question here is, even tho I popped the current screen, the remaining lines of the onpressed function still works.. Can anyone explain how onPressed() function works in detail..?

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't do that? Every line of code gets executed unless you `return` from a function

Comment: @Ivo What I thought was, if the Navigator.pop(context) is performed, the screen pops away and so the context variable of that screen, and the next line will not be executed because of the absence of the context value

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the logic of your code, you want to navigate by the Navigator.pop. The Navigator.pop is not a return in the onPressed, so you will still execute your Navigator.push.

What you have to do: You call a Navigator.push before, which redirects you to this page. Navigator.push is a future, that means you can use the wait keyword.

After the await you then call the

```
Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (ctx) => const Filter(),
                  ),
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Its normal,

**Navigator.pop(context);** will remove the top Route from the navigation stack and Navigator.push() will push another route to the navigation stack

it doesn't mean that the second statement won't be executed because both are part of the function and they will be executed in sequence.

you should use **if else statement** in this case.

Comment: What I thought was, if the Navigator.pop(context) is performed, the screen pops away and so the context variable of that screen, and the next line will not be executed because of the absence of the context value.

Comment: the screen will be popped away from the Navigation stack but the method registered will continue working and finishes all statements,
try to put a condition to prevent such case.

Answer (score 0):

A method will execute the instructions given to it in order.

If the call to `Navigator.pop` is not throwing an exception (which would cause the entire method to crash) the rest of the instructions will be executed, in your case the call to `Navigator.push`. The reference to `context` might be modified after the pop but keep in mind that it won't stop the execution.

If you take a look at the documentation of the [`popAndPushNamed`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/popAndPushNamed.html) method you'll see that it's similar to your implementation:

```dart
Future<T?> popAndPushNamed<T extends Object?, TO extends Object?>(
  String routeName, {
  TO? result,
  Object? arguments,
}) {
  pop<TO>(result);
  return pushNamed<T>(routeName, arguments: arguments);
}
```